# reduce time of save encodings face recognition

Tags: python, pickle

i have a dataset and i am saving the result of the encoding of the images for fave recognition in pickle object.
i would like to add new images or delete images in database and when i do it then prior images that exist in the database are stored in dataset_faces.dat and only for new images encode_faces.py be done.
I want to reduce the time to save the encoding in the encoding.pickle.
Otherwise, a lot of time should be spent even adding a new image.

```
encode_faces.py

import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
known_person = []
known_image= []
known_face_encoding=[]

for file in os.listdir("Imagefolder"):

        #Extracting person name from the image filename eg:Abhilash.jpg
        known_person.append(str(file).replace(".jpg", ""))
        file=os.path.join("Imagefolder", file)
        known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)
        known_face_encoding.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0])

        with open('dataset_faces.dat', 'wb') as f:
             pickle.dump(known_face_encoding, f,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

        with open('dataset_fac.dat', 'wb') as d:
             pickle.dump(known_person, d)



print(known_face_encoding)
print(known_person)
```

Comment: Although I'm not entirely sure about what you're asking, this doesn't look like it even works to me. You're hard-coded the output file name in a`for` loop so I'm pretty sure that it just overwrites all your data on each loop.

Comment: So what should I do to when i add just the new images added to the imagefolder or when I delete the image then the pickle only works on new images

Comment: I don't know. You need to have some way of identifying each pickle file; a unique identifier for the pickle file name that allows you to get at the data you want. You'd need something similar if you were to store data in a database. Have you checked to see your approach even works before asking or are you taking my word that it doesn't work?

Comment: Is the code indentation correct? If it is correct then it's  rewriting the pickle  files on _every_ iteration? Moving the pickle writing code outside of the loop should speed it up somewhat.